# Connect multiple AD's to one site

Tags: users

Is it possible to connect 2 AD's to drupal intranet to have single sign on (with the LDAP module)?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. After installing the ldap module:

1. Set up the two servers via: admin/config/people/ldap/servers
2. Set up authentication via: admin/config/people/ldap/authentication. Make
   sure to "Check all LDAP server configurations to use in authentication."
3. Do your other settings as per your requirements.